# Wild automorphisms of $\mathbb C$ in Wigner's theorem

Tags: hilbert-spaces, projective-geometry

There is an interesting proof of Wigner's unitary-antiunitary theorem by Kai Johannes Keller which is based on the fundamental theorem of projective geometry. ([On the realization of symmetries in quantum mechanics](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0997) ). The conclusion of this paper is the following.

> [image]

But the highlighted statement is false since we know that besides the identity and the complex conjugation, [there are also so-called "wild" automorphisms of $\mathbb C$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/automorphism+of+the+complex+numbers). Does this mean that Keller's proof isn't complete (since it doesn't prove that the transformation can be linear or anti-linear), or Wigner's theorem isn't true (because there are some symmetries that cannot be obtained from unitary or anti-unitary transformation, only from some wild semi-linear transformation?

Comment: So I followed their reference to Artin's proof (page 88 of "Geometric Algebra"), and he constructs $\sigma$ (he calls it $x\to x'$) without using the Axiom of Choice. Therefore, $\sigma$ cannot be a wild automorphism.